# Pip install not installing python module

Tags: python, powershell, beautifulsoup, pip

I recently reformatted my computer, and I've been trying to reinstall Python and Pip and the modules I use for programming. However, when I try to install modules with pip in powershell, for example "pip install BeautifulSoup", it displays

```
PS C:\Users\Norman\Copy\Coding\LinguisticsProject> pip install BeautifulSoup
Downloading/unpacking pip
Downloading/unpacking setuptools
Downloading/unpacking install
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement install
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external install to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for install
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Norman\pip\pip.log
```

The log file can be found at http://pastebin.com/Th7uuKA4. The module is not installing correctly, because the module is not found when I try to import it. I have my user PATH variable set to the following: http://pastebin.com/htquhuVY. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `pip install BeautifulSoup4`?

Comment: I tried that as well and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the package you are looking for is `BeautifulSoup4`.  I failed this too.  I feel your pain.

Comment: I've tried that, it still doesn't work. I think it has something to do with my pip installation, not a wrong name.